# Save a rmarkdown ioslides presentation as standalone website

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rstudio-server

I would like to save the presentation generated by knitr as a html file. Which I am able to share with people as standalone html file.

If I use *Run Document* button in R studio (server) this generates a file with the .Rmd extension.

````
---
title: "Standalone"
author: "MarketRedesign"
date: "10-7-2014"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Knit HTML button (default Control + Shift + H) doesn't work?

Comment: No, I think this doesn't work anymore in R Studio version 0.98.945

Comment: You should only see the Run Document button if it's a Shiny presentation (i.e. has `runtime: shiny`). Do you see for the document above? Have you tried updating RStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the knit HTML button, a HTML file IS always created by RStudio in the same directory as the R Markdown file lives in. The HTML file will also have the same name as the R Markdown file that was used to create it.