# R Shiny app embedded in PowerPoint

Tags: r, shiny, powerpoint, r-markdown, reporters

Let's consider a simple `r shiny` application

```
# Global variables can go here
n <- 200
# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)
# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}
# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to implement this application into my (Microsoft) PowerPoint presentation without losing its interactivity. I tried some things, but with little success:

- [ReporteRs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReporteRs/ReporteRs.pdf) package is promising, but I couldn’t find the way to directly include shiny application.
- Another way is to install a [gadget](https://www.r-bloggers.com/embedding-r-generated-interactive-html-pages-in-ms-powerpoint/) for live web pages into PowerPoint. In this case I can host my application on a web server and connect to that server with PowerPoint. But I don’t want that (there are sometimes problems with internet …).
- Thirdly, I could create a presentation in R Markdown and later implement it into PowerPoint, but also didn’t find the way to do it.
  So, are there any suggestions?

Comment: I referenced to this blog in my question (gadget). The problem is, I don't want to be dependent on internet connection…

Comment: Have you considered the method(s) described here: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2015/10/programmatically-create-interactive-powerpoint-slides-with-r.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have, but could not find the way to use it as a solution for my problem. So far, I believe the following could be a solution: make a presentation with r Markdown (one slide) and save it as html. After html should be uploaded into PowerPoint...

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is a rmarkdown ioslides/slidy presentation with shiny runtime, instead of powerpoint

Comment: @Hao I will explore your suggestion and come back with my feedback.

Comment: @JerryTheForester http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html

Comment: @Hao, yes I agree. With R Markdown I can create interactive slides as creative as I can imagine. But consider this situation: I create my fancy R Markdown slides and I travel to the conference to the country X. They expect me to send them my presentation or save it on a dropbox etc. So I will not use my computer for presentation. So, I could deploy my presentation on shiny server, but I am again dependent on their internet connection. That's why I would like to implement my presentation into (well accepted) and usually fine PowerPoint.

Comment: Alternatively, stand-alone html format of markdown presentation would be fine, since I can open it with any browser… Am I missing something, or do you agree with me?

Comment: Ok, I see I am wrong. The solution of my problem is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679518/save-a-rmarkdown-ioslides-presentation-as-standalone-website) Thank you for your support @Hao

Comment: @JerryTheForester hmm.....I don't want to get you wrong.. The output of a regular rmarkdown slides is just a html file. You can use it anywhere without internet connection. *You can use limited interactivities without re-calculation using htmlwidgets/javascript.* (see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) However, if you want to use shiny runtime in rmarkdown, you have to run it on a computer with at least R (better with Rstudio) because shiny runtime means results will be recalculated by R in shiny to achieve interactivity

Comment: @Hao, Ok, I see I will need to deepen my knowledge and experience with RMarkdown first and after I will come back. Thank you for now. Cheers